# Possible to send auto-reply to friend requests directing them to a fan page?

Tags: facebook-wall

I am working on a fan page, the owner has almost 5,000 friends on their personal page and wants to direct incoming friend requests to their fan page. They get dozens a day so doing this manually, one-by-one is a daunting, time-consuming task.
So I'm looking to have all users who send the personal account a friend request receive a message that says "Thank you for your request to connect, sorry I have too many friends, please connect by liking my fan page at -link-." (or something like that).
Any script/setting that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Graph API doesn't have a way to send messages to users as this would get abused heavily by spammers.  And if it did, it would probably only allow messages to be sent to friends, which these users aren't yet.  There is also no way to respond to friend requests via the API (although friend requests can be read).

You would have to look for some kind of script that scrapes Facebook which would be against their terms of service and probably off topic for this site.

The easiest solution would be to hide the user's account, or convert the account to a fan page, or post a final status that says to like this page instead.